# ¿Cómo hago una concatenación de variables en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

consigna;
Declará y asigná tres variables, una con tu nombre, otra con tu apellido y otra con tu edad. Luego en la variable resultado forma la siguiente oración usando variables: “Pasado el tiempo, Juana Manso va a tener XX”. Respetá los espacios!

```
var nombre ="Juana"
var apellido="Manso"
var edad=(28);
```

LA PARTE DE LA VARIABLE DE RESULTADO NO LOGRO QUE ME SALGA
ME AYUDAN?

Comment: Una pista.  Para concatenar en javascript se usa el signo `+`.

Comment: `var tarea= \`Pasado el tiempo,  ${nombre}  ${apellido} va a tener ${edad}\` `

Answer (score 10):

Normalmente no respondería una pregunta así, pero visto en que en SO en español no hay preguntas concretas sobre cómo concatenar cadenas en Javascript (o al menos no encontré 100% duplicadas para pedir cerrar la pregunta)...

**Hay variasmaneras de llegar al resultado que buscas**

La mas facil de todas es crear una concatenación con el operador `+`

```
var resultado = "Pasado el tiempo, "+nombre+" "+apellido+" va a tener "+edad;
```

Desde ES6 (funciona a partir de >IE11) se puede usar el backtick  ` para crear cadenas interpoladas:

```
var resultado = `Pasado el tiempo, ${nombre} ${apellido} va a tener ${edad}`
```

Puedes usar el método `string.concat(string)` para crear una cadena pero es un proceso que repercute mas en el performace:

```
var resultado="Pasado el tiempo, ";
resultado = resultado.concat(nombre);
resultado = resultado.concat(" ");
resultado = resultado.concat(apellido);
resultado = resultado.concat(" va a tener ");
resultado = resultado.concat(edad);
```

Todas dan como resultado la misma cadena:

`Pasado el tiempo, Juana Manso va a tener 28`

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Declaras las variables y las mandas a imprimir de este modo

```js
      var resultado
        var nombre ="Juana"
        var apellido="Manso"
        var edad=(28);
        
        resultado = "Pasado el tiempo, "+nombre+" "+apellido+" va a tener "+edad
        console.log(resultado)
```

El signo de mas ayuda a **concatenar** es decir unir valores para poder mostrarlos juntos

O desde ES6, puedes usar las template strings encerrando la cadena completa entre comillas invertidas y metiendo las variables entre `${variable}`

```js
var resultado
var nombre ="Juana"
var apellido="Manso"
var edad=(28);

resultado = `Pasado el tiempo, ${nombre} ${apellido} va a tener ${edad}`
console.log(resultado)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var nombre="nombre";
var apellido="apellido";
var edad =14;
var tag= document.getElementById("resultado");
tag.innerHTML="Esta persona es: "+nombre+" "+apellido+" "+" y tiene "+edad+" años";
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda siempre colocar el **;** al terminar la declaración de tu variable.

```js
var nombre ="Juana";
var apellido="Manso";
var edad=(28);

var resultado = "Pasado el tiempo, "+nombre+" "+apellido+" va a tener "+edad;

alert(resultado);
console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: puede ser que salga este error?

solucion.js:9
resultado= "Pasado el tiempo, "+nombre+" "+apellido+" va a tener "+edad
         ^

ReferenceError: resultado is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (solucion.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
    at Array.forEach (native)

Comment: Al parecer no has declarado la variable resultado. **var resultado**. Añade el prefijo var.

Answer (score 1):

Está creo que mal hacerte la tarea, para concatenar debes usar "+", 
Ejemplo:

```
var h = "hola";
var g = "mundo";
console.log(h+" "+g);
```

Comment: creo que esta mal juzgar, porque no es una tarea...

Comment: Fue solo una referencia, para poder explicar bien todo. Mil disculpas si sonó a juzgar, pero la idea del ejemplo debajo es para que vea mas claro todo como va. salu2

Comment: Te agradezo el comentario